# Doxygen does not recognize absolute path on windows with mingw

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, doxygen

Hi I am trying to generate my docs with cmake + doxygen. As stated in the cmake documentation for [FindDoxygen](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html) the output path:

> [...] will be converted to an absolute path relative to the current binary directory

Now in my build/Doxyfile.doxygen I have the option with the absolute windows path:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = D:/projects/MyProject/build/
```

But calling doxygen with this Doxyfile will produce:

```
error: Could not create output directory /d/projects/MyProject/D:/projects/MyProject/build/html
```

I am asuming this is because I'm using mingw and doxygen does not recognize the windows path as absolute and therefore tries to attach the cwd in front of it.

The relevant commands in my CMakeLists.txt look like this:

```
find_package(Doxygen
        REQUIRED dot
        OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS mscgen dia)

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    doxygen_add_docs(Doxygen)
endif()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:

- CMake Version: 3.20.2
- doxygen Version: 1.9.1 (ec8203f43232e7e7b16b1c85351c7c48d128f924)

Edit2:
I'm using clion to run CMake using the bundeled version. Running `cmake .. && make Doxyfile` from commandline works

Comment: How? The build/Doxyfile.doxygen is autogenerated from cmake

Comment: Which version of doxygen and CMake. Looks like the FindDoxygen might have the problem of not recognizing the used compilation system (Mingw) I also see that it lists `mscgen` at the optional components, but in the newer versions it is not used anymore (it is internal).

Comment: @albert I added the versions. Both commands are copied from the [official doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html)

Comment: Are you running your commands from MSYS2 command prompt? If not, that's one thing to try. Be sure to install cmake and doxygen packages from MSYS2. Otherwise does MinGW provides special packages for cmake and doxygen? Then you should use those rather than the windows installations.

Comment: I'm using clion with the mingw32 toolchain to run cmake.  Can't run `cmake` command in mingw32 as it can't find my python3 installation and using the bundeled cmake from clion works. cmake and doxygen are installed for mingw

Comment: @vre Ok commented out everything that required python and could then run cmake from mingw32. No I have the path `/d/projects/MyProject/build` as OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and make Doxygen works.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you have could be related to how you specify the path.

Windows style path will look like this:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = D:\projects\MyProject\build
```

while MSYS style path will look like this:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = /d/projects/MyProject/build
```

But specifying an absolute path is not a very good idea, especially if you want to distribute the source or move/copy it somewhere else.
It's best to just specify a folder relative to the location from where you will run `doxygen`, which in your case probably looks like this:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = build
```

Comment: As said in the comments to my question the `build/Doxyfile.doxygen` file is autogenerated by cmake. I can not edit the `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` directly.

Comment: Which `-G` flag did you use with `cmake`?

Comment: I used `CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles` for the MinGW Toolchain and `Visual Studio 16 2019` for the Visual Studio Toolchain in CLion.

Comment: Does it work with `-G"MinGW Makefiles"` and `mingw32-make`?

Comment: And does `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` have forward slashes or backslashes?

Comment: Forward slashes regardless of the generator or toolchain

Comment: Are you sure you're doing a clean `cmake` (i.e. cleaning up `CMakeFiles` and `CMakeCache.txt`) ?